# Could not create parent directory for lock in Gradle Build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> Gradle Build Error Error:Could not create parent directory for lock
>   file C:\Program Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\bin\gradle-4.4.1\bin\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1-all.zip.lck

[image]

I create a new project in Android Studio, but it keeps showing this error, I installed Gradle in Android Studio path and it also still there, help me please

Comment: Please let people know the error message. Then we could help.

Comment: Change your gradel version and then try to execute